# Need to show related products of simple product in configurable product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, blocks, related-products

I need to show related products block on configurable product page (as it is by deflault), but instead of related products of configurable product i need to show related products of simple products which are included in that configurable product.

Comment: ok but you can display only the products under configurable products that are visible and in stock with inventory will show. what you want here ?

Comment: i need that when i select simple product for any configurable product that simple product related product data should also be shown as related product in configurable product

Comment: so if you select any simple product it should be visibility should be catalog,search to front-end ,in stock and have inventory too then can list down in related products

Comment: Ok let me recorrect myself  when i redirect to any configurable product page i need to see related products  on that page but that related products should not be of that configurable product but of all the simple products attach to that configurable product

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to display related products of child items instead of the related products of the parent item in a configurable product structure, then

Create a new module and override `_prepareData` function the main block file

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Related.php
```

Something like

```
protected function _prepareData() {
    $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
    /* @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */

    // GET TYPE
    $productType = $product->getTypeId();

    // IF CONFIGURABLE
    if ($productType == 'configurable') {
        $childrenProducts = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($product);
        if ($childrenProducts) {
            $this->_itemCollection = array();
            foreach ($childrenProducts as $singleChild) {
                $relatedProductCollection = $singleChild->getRelatedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
                                'required_options'
                        )->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter();

                if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_Checkout')) {
                    $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($relatedProductCollection);
                }
                $relatedProductCollection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
                $relatedProductCollection->load();
                foreach ($relatedProductCollection as $singleProduct) {
                    $singleProduct->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
                    $this->_itemCollection[] = $singleProduct;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // IF OTHERS

        // main FUNCITON CODE
    }


    return $this;
}
```

and then override the `items.phtml` file

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml
```

under `case 'related'` change the if condition

```
if ($exist = $block->getItems()->getSize())
```

to

```
if ($exist = count($block->getItems()))
```